# New to Angular. Trying to pass data back to server using angular / webapi

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass data to server in angular using webapi. Thanks to people on the forum I was able to fill 1 drop down based on another using entity framework and angular.  The next thing I wanted to figure out was how to pass screen data back to the server using webapi.

When the angular code is being called I am getting an error:  badreq 'Http request configuration must be an object'

This error shows in the $http

I found an example online where it shows the ability of creating a parent model used by each of the html controls.  In the case of the example online they were using textboxes, but I am using select lists, but I assume this should also work.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate it!!

FOLLOW UP:  The problem I am having at this point seems to be that Data in the Angular saveattributecontroller states as UNDEFINED.  So the issue I don't believe at this point is the call to the webapi, but the data not being passed from "Detail" in the HTML.

FOLLOW UP 2: based on Lorenzo's comment below.  By putting the attributevaluecontroller around the submit button, I can now see the data passed to the saveattributecontroller in the attribute.js which is good.  I also realized I needed to reference Data.A and Data.V in the saveattributecontroller.  But now it seems the call to the WebAPIAttribute controller is not happening.  I tried both the way I originally had and the other way that was suggested earlier yet the call to the controller never seems to go through.  Can anyone help me with that?

Follow UP 3:  The error I am finding as I step through the angular javascript is Resource can't be found.  So I am assuming it is not finding the webapi controller for some reason.  It's probably something very simple, but I am not seeing it.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('attributeapp', []);
 
    myapp.controller('attributecontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/Attribute/AttributeIndex/').then(function (response) {
            $scope.Attributes = response.data;
        })
    })
 
 
    myapp.controller('attributevaluecontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getattributevalues = function (id)
        {
            $http.get('/Attribute/getattributevalues/' + id).then(function (response) {
                $scope.A = id;
                $scope.AttributeValues = response.data;
            })
        }
    })
 
 
    myapp.controller('saveattributecontroller', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.attributesave = function (Data) {
            var GetAll = new Object();
            GetAll.AttributeKey = Data.AttributeKey;
            GetAll.AttributeValueKey = Data.AttributeValueKey;
            $http({
                url: "WebAPIAttribute/attributesave",
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                data: GetAll,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.value = response;
            })
               .error(function (error) {
                   alert(error);
               });
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/attribute.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="attributeapp">
    <div data-ng-controller="attributecontroller">
         <span data-ng-controller="attributevaluecontroller">
         <select data-ng-model="detail.A" data-ng-change="getattributevalues(detail.A)" data-ng-options="Attribute.Attribute_Key as Attribute.Attribute_Desc for Attribute in Attributes"><option value="">--Select--</option></select><br />{{detail.A}}
         <select data-ng-model="detail.V" data-ng-options="Attribute_Value.Attribute_Value_Key as Attribute_Value.Attribute_Value_Desc for Attribute_Value in AttributeValues"><option value="">--Select--</option></select>{{detail.V}}
         </span>
        <br />
        <span data-ng-controller="saveattributecontroller">
            <input type="button" value="submit" data-ng-click="attributesave(detail)"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
//AttributeControler.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MVC_APP1.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
 
 
namespace MVC_APP1.Controllers
{
    public class AttributeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Attribute/
 
        public ActionResult AttributeIndex()
        {
            Cafe_CPDEntities objEntity = new Cafe_CPDEntities();
            var data = objEntity.Attributes.ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
 
        public ActionResult getattributevalues(int id)
        {
            Cafe_CPDEntities objEntity = new Cafe_CPDEntities();
            var data = objEntity.Attribute_Value.Where(m=>m.Attribute_Key==id);
            //string test = data.FirstOrDefault().Attribute_Value_Desc;
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public ActionResult attributesave(List<int> ReturnData)
        {
            return null;
        }
 
    }
}
```

```html
// WebAPIAttributeController.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
 
namespace MVC_APP1.Controllers
{
    public class WebAPIAttributeController : ApiController
    {
        public class GetAll
        {
            public string AttributeKey { get; set; }
            public string AttributeValueKey { get; set; }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public string attributesave(HttpRequestMessage request,
            [FromBody] GetAll getAll)
        {
            return "Data Reached";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you just do `$http.post("WebAPIAttribute/attributesave", GetAll)`?

Comment: Could you also add the HTTP post request that the app makes.

Comment: what happens if you change attributesave(detail) to attributesave($scope.detail) in your HTML? - is Data still undefined in your action?

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
    $scope.attributesave = function (Data) {
                var GetAll = new Object();
                GetAll.AttributeKey = Data.AttributeKey;
                GetAll.AttributeValueKey = Data.AttributeValueKey;
                $http.post("WebAPIAttribute/attributesave", getAll)
                   .then(function(response){
                      //here your operations
                   })
                }
```

Comment: I added a follow up above.  The problem at this point is that Data in the saveattributecontroller on the attribute.js is showing UNDEFINED.  So the data is not being passed from the HTML for some reason.  Not saying your answer is not good, but I did just try that and I'm still having the same problem.  Thanks so much for the very fast response.  You guys are awesome!!

Comment: I believe that the problem is that you are trying to access to sibling controller scope with save attributesController.
Try to see this for comunication beetwen two sibling controller
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709769/communicating-between-sibling-scopes-in-angular

Comment: Lorenzo, that helped me get further as mentioned in my second follow up above, but now I seem to be stuck at the call to webapi controller not going through.   Thank you!

Comment: I added the new call to the saveattribute (WEB API) controller that seems to be having a problem finding.

Answer (score 0):

(I THOUGHT I POSTED THIS EARLIER, BUT IT DID NOT SAVE)

I figured out the last part.  I needed to add api/ to the route.

api/WebAPIAttributes/attributesave/

The call to webapi now goes through and passes the data from the screen.

Thanks so much to all those who helped answer the earlier issues I was having.